# how to get the rotation degree of picture in memory?

Tags: android, image, rotation

It is necessary to know the rotation degree when use Android camera to take picture or select pictures from album, a commonly used method is, 
`ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface (path);` 
but this method need to know the file path of the image, how to use ExifInterface to get the degree of pictures in memory? Or How to get the degree of pictures in the memory?

Comment: If the image is in memory, you can't get the ExifInterface, since Exif is only applied to file

Comment: so how to get the degree of pictures in memory?

Comment: You must rotate the image(bitmap) first from the file before it ended in memory, or you can save the reference of the bitmap path to be used to get the rotation degree

Comment: I don't think it works.Because I use the callback interface Camera.PictureCallback to take picture, the method onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) in the callback returns a byte array used to store image photos , the file as you say above doesn't appear in this process.

Comment: Hmm i don't think it works like you think. Since as far as i know, camera will save the picture directly to the file path that you provide, the byte[] data is just a thumbnail, refer to this link http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: you are right,but what you documented above is use MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to take photo.I use surfaceview to take photo,and the byte[] aren't automatically written to the file.

Comment: Hmm, i see. Then you can get the rotation degree with getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();